# Effect on the Result of a Formula After Changing the Value of a Variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is as follows:

> A formula to estimate the monthly payment, *p* dollars on a short-term loan is

$$ p = \frac{\frac{1}{2}ary + a}{12y}$$

> where *a* is the amount of loan, *r* is the annual interest rate expressed as a decimal, and *y* is the length of the loan. When *a* is multiplied by $2$, what is the effect on *p*?

I tried to substitute numerical values in for the variables, and got the answer to be that *p* would be divided by $6$, but that is not the correct answer. Can someone explain how to answer this question? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

reordering you have
$$
p=\frac{ry+2}{24y} a
$$

substitute $2a$.....